zoneinfo is missing timezone names that pytz has
I am comparing the timezone names that pytz and zoneinfo support because I would like to transition to zoneinfo from pytz.
It seems that zoneinfo lacks a lot of timezones:
>>> import pytz
>>> from backports import zoneinfo
>>> zoneinfo.available_timezones() - pytz.all_timezones_set
{'localtime', 'Factory'}
>>> list(sorted(pytz.all_timezones_set - zoneinfo.available_timezones()))
['Africa/Asmera', 'America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia', 'America/Buenos_Aires', 'America/Catamarca', 'America/Cordoba', 'America/Fort_Wayne', 'America/Godthab', 'America/Indianapolis', 'America/Jujuy', 'America/Knox_IN', 'America/Louisville', 'America/Mendoza', 'America/Rosario', 'Antarctica/South_Pole', 'Asia/Ashkhabad', 'Asia/Calcutta', 'Asia/Chungking', 'Asia/Dacca', 'Asia/Katmandu', 'Asia/Macao', 'Asia/Rangoon', 'Asia/Saigon', 'Asia/Thimbu', 'Asia/Ujung_Pandang', 'Asia/Ulan_Bator', 'Atlantic/Faeroe', 'Australia/ACT', 'Australia/LHI', 'Australia/NSW', 'Australia/North', 'Australia/Queensland', 'Australia/South', 'Australia/Tasmania', 'Australia/Victoria', 'Australia/West', 'Brazil/Acre', 'Brazil/DeNoronha', 'Brazil/East', 'Brazil/West', 'Canada/Atlantic', 'Canada/Central', 'Canada/Eastern', 'Canada/Mountain', 'Canada/Newfoundland', 'Canada/Pacific', 'Canada/Saskatchewan', 'Canada/Yukon', 'Chile/Continental', 'Chile/EasterIsland', 'Cuba', 'Egypt', 'Eire', 'Europe/Kiev', 'Europe/Uzhgorod', 'Europe/Zaporozhye', 'GB', 'GB-Eire', 'GMT+0', 'GMT-0', 'GMT0', 'Greenwich', 'Hongkong', 'Iceland', 'Iran', 'Israel', 'Jamaica', 'Japan', 'Kwajalein', 'Libya', 'Mexico/BajaNorte', 'Mexico/BajaSur', 'Mexico/General', 'NZ', 'NZ-CHAT', 'Navajo', 'PRC', 'Pacific/Enderbury', 'Pacific/Ponape', 'Pacific/Truk', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'ROC', 'ROK', 'Singapore', 'Turkey', 'UCT', 'US/Alaska', 'US/Aleutian', 'US/Arizona', 'US/Central', 'US/East-Indiana', 'US/Eastern', 'US/Hawaii', 'US/Indiana-Starke', 'US/Michigan', 'US/Mountain', 'US/Pacific', 'US/Samoa', 'Universal', 'W-SU', 'Zulu']

Questions
I wonder:

How can I make sure that all of them are supported when switching to zoneinfo?
Why is there this difference between pytz and zoneinfo?

Context:

icalendar#623
icalendar#609


concerning the why: the IANA tz database changes over time since time zones are subject to political decisions. As soon as one library uses a different version of the tz database than another, you're in for surprises.

Now, I found the solution.
zoneinfo is supplied with a set of timezones by default. This is the set mentioned.
You also should install the tzdata module as that updates the timezone information.
pip install tzdata

Now the difference is gone:
>>> list(sorted(pytz.all_timezones_set - zoneinfo.available_timezones()))
[]


See also:

docs/zoneinfo


you have to install tzdata on Windows. On other platforms, such as Unix derivatives that come with the IANA tz database, the zoneinfo module will default to use that - unless you tell it to use a specific tz database via zoneinfo.reset_tzpath(to=[path-to-your-db]).
